# Monty Hall game incorrect results

Tags: java

I made a practice project to demonstrate the Monty Hall problem, but it's giving the wrong output. For those unfamiliar with the paradox:

> Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?

Everything online says your chances of winning are doubled by switching your choice, because switching your choice will always reverse the outcome and you are more likely to make the wrong choice when you have more doors to choose from. I've been thinking about this long enough that I understand the logic, and I don't know why my program isn't working. This is the output (give or take 1%) each time it's run:

```
Games where initial choice was changed: 
Won: 49%
Lost: 50%

Games where initial choice was not changed: 
Won: 49%
Lost: 50%
```

Here is my code, please let me know what I'm missing.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int won = 0;
        int lost = 0;
        int wonChanged = 0;
        int lostChanged = 0;
        int passes = 100000;

        for (int i = 0; i < passes; i++) {
            MontyHall problem = new MontyHall();
            int choice = problem.getRandom();

            if (problem.isCar(choice)) {
                won++;
            } else {
                lost++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < passes; i++) {
            MontyHall problem = new MontyHall();
            int choice = problem.getRandom();
            int hostChoice = problem.hostChoice();

            // Choice is changed
            choice = problem.otherDoor(choice, hostChoice);

            if (problem.isCar(choice)) {
                wonChanged++;
            } else {
                lostChanged++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("1,000,000 tests were done for each case. These are the results:\n");
        System.out.println("Games where initial choice was changed: " +
                "\nWon: " + wonChanged / (passes / 100) + "%" +
                "\nLost: " + lostChanged / (passes / 100) + "%");
        System.out.println("\nGames where initial choice was not changed: " +
                "\nWon: " + won / (passes / 100) + "%" +
                "\nLost: " + lost / (passes / 100) + "%");
    }
}
```

```
public MontyHall() {
        doors = new char[3];

        // Puts car behind a random door
        int index = getRandom();
        doors[index] = car;

        // Puts goats behind the other two doors
        for (int i = 0; i < doors.length; i++) {
            if (doors[i] != car) {
                doors[i] = goat;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    }

    public int hostChoice() {
        int index = getRandom();

        // Ensures the host opens a goat door
        while (doors[index] != goat) {
            index = getRandom();
        }
        return index;
    }

    public int otherDoor(int a, int b) {
        int newChoice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < doors.length; i++) {
            if (!(doors[i] == a || doors[i] == b)) {
                newChoice = i;
            }
        }
        return newChoice;
    }

    public boolean isCar(int i) {
        return (doors[i] == car);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few mistakes. First, the logic of `getRandom()` is incorrect. `nextInt(2)` returns 0 or 1. `nextInt(2) + 1` gives you 1 or 2. If you want a random selection between 0, 1, and 2, you need just `nextInt(3)`:

```
public int getRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(3);
}
```

Second, `hostChoice()` needs to avoid selecting the door that's already open:

```
public int hostChoice(int choice) {
    int index = getRandom();

    // Ensures the host opens a closed goat door
    while (index == choice || doors[index] != goat) {
        index = getRandom();
    }
    return index;
}
```

Third, the `otherDoor()` method is comparing indexes `a` and `b` to the *contents* at `door[i]`. You should be comparing them to `i` itself:

```
public int otherDoor(int a, int b) {
    int newChoice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < doors.length; i++) {
        if (!(i == a || i == b)) {
            newChoice = i;
        }
    }
    return newChoice;
}
```

Making these changes yields:

```
Games where initial choice was changed: 
Won: 66%
Lost: 33%

Games where initial choice was not changed: 
Won: 33%
Lost: 66%
```

In the future, you should learn how to use the debugger, which will enable you to follow the execution path and see the exact value of each variable and argument at every stage of the experiment. This will quickly reveal when and why things go wrong, like doors being ignored or opened repeatedly. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I made those changes and it's working correctly for the games with no change, but where the choice was changed it's still 49/50. There must still be something wrong with my otherDoor() method, but it looks the same as your solution

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include one of the fixes. See my update.